# Android: strange text wrapping issue with TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, word-wrap

I have a TextView in a LinearLayout.
The textview's XML

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:background="@color/CLOUDS"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    />
```

[image: Error 1]

On the right we see the textview set with text: **"Campanario Blanco\nMistral Ice\nMistral"** The last word is not displayed.

On the left we have another textview with weight 10. 
Both are placed within a Linear layout.

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context.mContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.topMargin = 2;
    ll.bottomMargin = 0;
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(ll);
    linearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bubble.addView(linearLayout);
```

Now if I change the content of the view to **"Campanario Blanco\nMistral Ice\nMistral\nMalibu"** Now 'mistral' is visible, but the new last work 'Mailbu' is not.

[image: Error 2]

As shown the total line count is equal to the sum of the \n but it doesn't take into account the wrapping of the first string.
If we remove the long text, it works as expected. **"Mistral Ice\nMistral\nMalibu"**

[image: NO error]

Comment: Where are you setting the line count?

Comment: I have no line count. I set the height as wrap_text. The information about the number of lines, is just a deduction on how its been wrapping automaticlly.

Comment: Strange. As workaround you can add an extra newline though. Bug with TextView?

Comment: Yes but lets say if  i set   "very long string A\n very long string B\n short string"  I would  have to add 2 extra lines - this would work - but due to multiple screen sizes/resolutions I dont know if "very long string A" uses one or two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this, use like this

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:padding="6dp"
     android:background="#358576"
     tools:context="com.example.yujcore7.myapplicationtextviewdemo.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Marca(s)" />

<TextView
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Campanario Blanco\nMistral Ice\nMistral\nMalibu" />
```

use this layout and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. My initial layout was something like this, It should work but it wasn't . So I looked up in the hierarchy, one of the parent linear layout was set as width: WRAP_CONTENT, and one of it's child had a fixed width. So this weird wrapping error occurred. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @swanand-vaidya I tracked the error down. One of the parent's parent's had a wrap_content set.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/WET_ASPHALT"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0D97FC"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/AMETHYST_DARK"
        android:text="line1 hello world hello world hello world hello world \nline2 hello world hello\nline 3hello world\nline4 hello world world"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result of this layout is

[image]

Line4 is not displayed.
As the top-most linear-layout has wrap_conent.

When the top-most layout has a fixed value or match_parent.
All lines are correctly displayed.